# Entity Framework Database Submit

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

using the following code:

```
using (GagaShaggyContext db = new GagaShaggyContext())
{
    ItemModel itemToChange = null;

    itemToChange = (from i in db.Items
                    where i.ItemID == checkoutItem.Item.ItemID
                    select i).FirstOrDefault();

    itemToChange.FrontFeature = false;

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The model is saving back to the database with a brand new ID, which I want to save changes to the original database entry. Is there any reason for this to happen?

Thanks

**Edit**

On breakpoint analysis adding the receipt item before hand is adding a different ItemID not that I can see why:

```
using (var db = new GagaShaggyContext())
{
                    db.Receipts.Add(rec);
                    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Can we see your mapping code for your model?

Comment: do you really select an item? Maybe the `Default` part of `FirstOrDefault` is used and therefore a new item created

Comment: @Igor http://pastebin.com/SKQMkjmr

Comment: @Dominik The item is being retrieved

Comment: @TobusBoulton What is the value of the ItemID for the newly created record? If it is the same in the new record as the existing then your DB schema is wrong as well as your mapping code because neither recognize the primary key. Your db table should be setup with a PK constraint on ItemID. Also is this a db generated value (identity)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (var db = new GagaShaggyContext())
     {
        var ItemToUse = (from i in db.ItemModels
                         where i.ItemModelID == checkoutItem.Item.ItemModelID
                         select i).FirstOrDefault();
        rec.ItemModel = ItemToUse;
        db.Receipts.Add(rec);
        db.SaveChanges();
      }
```

This fixed it. We need to actually retrieve the relevant Item and put it inside the Receipt (rec) then we could add it, now that Entity Framework recognizes the relationship between these two.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to Insert into DB

```
    using (GagaShaggyContext db = new GagaShaggyContext())
    {
        ItemModel itemToChange = new ItemModel();
        itemToChange = (from i in db.Items
                        where i.ItemID == checkoutItem.Item.ItemID
                        select i).FirstOrDefault();
        if(itemToChange !=null)
        {
            itemToChange.FrontFeature = false;
            db .Items.Add(itemToChange);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
   }
```

If you are trying to Update the record than

```
using (GagaShaggyContext db = new GagaShaggyContext())
    {
        ItemModel itemToChange = new ItemModel();
        itemToChange = (from i in db.Items
                        where i.ItemID == checkoutItem.Item.ItemID
                        select i).FirstOrDefault();
        if(itemToChange !=null)
        {
            itemToChange.FrontFeature = false;    
            objDBContext.Entry(itemToChange).State = EntityState.Modified;
            objDBContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```